# How to find Android Bluetooth version?

Tags: android, bluetooth, version

I need to programatically find Android Bluetooth version on the phone. Can someone me tips how to do that?

Answer (score 6):

As far as i know (and i did a lot of research) **there is no way to find out what the hardware version is of your Android bluetooth device**. (4.0, 4.2, 5.0,...)

Some people claim they have an app that can do this, but i never saw a working example. These apps show you a lot of version numbers but not the Bluetooth hardware version.

Some people come up with a trick that shows you the version number of the bluetooth software, but that is not what we want to know.

There are some tricks to get the capabilities of the bluetooth device, but again, that is not what we want to know.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, with android you can distinguish only presence of Bluetooth or Bluetooth_LE. But I am doubtful about android support on identifying Bluetooth versions (e.g. BT2.0, BT2.1+EDR, BT3.0 etc). 
The way to programatically identify the BT or BLE presence only could be:

```
PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
boolean isBT = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH);
boolean isBLE = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE);
```

Thereafter, using isBT or isBLE flags, the app flow can be directed.

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, but isnt these systemFeatured checkers for checking if the uses-feature is set to required or not: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>

Comment: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/> tells the Google Play Store not to show the app to users with devices that do not support bt_le for example.

Answer (score -1):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>

// Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device. Then
// you can selectively disable BLE-related features.
if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
}
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Comment: This is a very random answer and it is also incorrect given you are making BLE mandatory in that manifest. Did you read the question?

Answer (score -3):

You just try the following way to find bluetooth version.

Androidmanifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
    android:required="false" />
```

Write coding in onCreate()

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device.  Then you can
    // selectively disable BLE-related features.
    if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //  finish();
    }

    // Initializes a Bluetooth adapter.  For API level 18 and above, get a reference to
    // BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
            (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    // Checks if Bluetooth is supported on the device.
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // finish();
        return;
    }
}
```

Write coding in onResume()

```
protected void onResume() {
    mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();
    setListAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);
}
```

Adapter

```
// Adapter for holding devices found through scanning.
private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;

    private LayoutInflater mInflator;

    public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
        super();
        //mLeDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

        mInflator = DeviceScanActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    public void addDevice(BluetoothDeviceModel device, int rssiValue, String address) {

       Log.d("TAG", "map size is : " + mapBluetoothDevice.size());
    }



    public List<BluetoothDevice> getDevice(int position) {
        return mLeDevices.get(position);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mLeDevices.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mLeDevices.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {

        return mLeDevices.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        // General ListView optimization code.
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
            viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
            viewHolder.deviceRssi = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_rssi);
            viewHolder.deviceDistance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_distance);

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(i);

        final String deviceName = device.getName();

        if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0)
            viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
        else
            viewHolder.deviceName.setText(R.string.unknown_device);

        viewHolder.deviceRssi.setText("Version : " + device.getVersion());
        viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getDevice().getBluetoothAddress());

        }

        viewHolder.deviceDistance.setText("Distance : " + String.valueOf(distance));
        return view;
    }
```

This is core coding when you interact with bluetooth.

Comment: it doesn't really help to find out which version of bluetooth phone supports