# How can you find Bluetooth version programmatically in Java?

Tags: android, bluetooth, ibeacon

For a Bluetooth beacon distance measuring app I am currently using the [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/).

I am testing my measurements with 2 devices. One device has Bluetooth 5.0 (Samsung Galaxy s10+), the other phone has Bluetooth 4.2 (Samsung Galaxy s7 edge). While testing, I discovered that the distance to the beacon is different for more than 100% if the phones are at the exact same spot. This is (I think) because of the difference in signal strength. I think I could solve this if I can detect the Bluetooth version of the users' phone.

Does someone know how you could detect that?
This question has already been asked before but that was ~8 years ago and at that time it wasn't possible. Maybe someone has discovered a new method in the meantime...

Comment: Did you mean [Combine iBeacon bluetooth low energy with Android 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17875430/995926)? Btw the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23907774/995926).

Comment: No I need to figure out which Bluetooth version a phone has. 5.0 or 4.x for example. The link you provided shows how you can detect whether a phone supports BLE but Bluetooth 4.x and 5.0 both support that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of research, I concluded that it still isn't possible to discover the exact Bluetooth version of an android phone. But I came up with a workaround. If you look at phones that support android 10, almost all of them support Bluetooth 5.0 and the phones that don't support Android 10 almost all have Bluetooth 4.x. So I now find the Bluetooth version of an android phone by looking at the Android version and act accordingly.

I have tested it and it has worked well for my use-case.