# How to get BLE version from Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I want to find out Android Bluetooth version on the phone.How can i find out the currently supported BLE version.I know that i can find out the BT or BLE presence from below code.But i didnt find any solution to find out the BLE version from the device.

```
    packageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
boolean isBT = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH);
boolean isBLE = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE);
```

Comment: I don't think something did change from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126512/how-to-find-android-bluetooth-version
Could you tell us more about your goal? Maybe there is another solution to your problem

Answer (score 3):

The Bluetooth version itself is often quite meaningless since all new features introduced in a particular version is more or less always optional to implement.

It's much better to perform a feature detection to find out if something is supported.

On https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter you have a bunch of is*Supported methods you can use to check support for a particular feature.